# How to draw a square on a video and track the object enclosed by the square

Tags: c#, image-processing, tracking

I am doing a Final Year Project to track an object(human) by drawing a square around a human in a video. I am doing this project in C# .NET.

I asked in a forum about this and they said to use GDI+ and mouse handling (which I have no clue about).

Do I have to do segmentation and then identify the region where the square was drawn,
splitting the video to frames perhaps?

Comment: That's a huge homework question. We can't help you with your entire Final Year Project! If you have no clue how to start, maybe you should take a course on image recognition?

Comment: haha, I didnt ask you to do my project and give me the code did I ? I just asked what should be done. I want to know, what to do after drawing a square around the object being tracked. >> take a background model or split the frames. Jeezz

Comment: Are you after tracking the image (shape recognition), or how to draw the square, or both?

Comment: ok im drawing a square enclosing an object for instance, a human face. Then the system should track tht face. Note there is no face comparison wit a database or something. I want to know how to draw a square on a streaming video and what process should be done to track it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think DirectX would be a better...

.NET Video overlay drawing
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/article.php/c1229/

Comment: thks for ur comment but DirectShow is for C++ users right ?? I am using C#.NET and dshownet. Any other ways ??

Comment: There is .NET wrappers which can be used by VB.NET or C#

Comment: 404 link is dead